# elasticsearch autosuggest fetch only text data

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I am new to elasticsearch.Now I am using elasticsearch5.6.

POST localhost:9200/hotels/_suggest

req-body: {
  "hotels" : {
    "text" : "m",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "name_suggest"
    }
  }
}

response

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hotels": [
        {
            "text": "m",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": "Marriot Munich City",
                    "_index": "hotels",
                    "_type": "hotel",
                    "_id": "3",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "name": "Courtyard by Marriot Munich City",
                        "city": "Munich",
                        "name_suggest": {
                            "input": [
                                "Courtyard by Marriot Munich City",
                                "Marriot Munich City"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "text": "Monaco Munich",
                    "_index": "hotels",
                    "_type": "hotel",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "name": "Hotel Monaco",
                        "city": "Munich",
                        "name_suggest": {
                            "input": [
                                "Monaco Munich",
                                "Hotel Monaco"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way , where I can exclude _source in response?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution i.e.

POST localhost:9200/hotels/_search

> {   "_source" : false,   "suggest" : {
>       "hotels" : {
>         "text" : "m",
>         "completion" : {
>           "field" : "name_suggest",
>           "size" : 10
>         }
>       }   } }